# How do I embed a KML map using the "new" Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-api, embeddable-web-maps

I have a [KML link](http://share.abvio.com/9d18/de58/4d38/a340/Cyclemeter-Cycle-20140629-0905.kml) that I can use to generate an embedded Google Map using "old" Google Maps and would like to use it instead to create a "new" Google Map embedding.

To generate the an "old" embedding, all I need to do is click on the link icon on the [page for my KML](https://maps.google.com/?q=http://share.abvio.com/9d18/de58/4d38/a340/Cyclemeter-Cycle-20140629-0905.kml), which generates an `iframe` I can use for embedding:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?q=http:%2F%2Fshare.abvio.com%2F9d18%2Fde58%2F4d38%2Fa340%2FCyclemeter-Cycle-20140629-0905.kml&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=42.429738,-71.31901&amp;spn=0.135997,0.21338&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

But this is an "old style" embedding, and I would like to generate a "new style" one from the same KML. Is there a simple mapping from one to the other or from my KML URL directly to the form of the "new `iframe`?

Comment: Note: The workflow needs to be as described, from KML URL to embedding. I don't have an opportunity to intervene and save or edit the KML, or change it's location.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how to embedd the map, but I merely put some kml in a public folder on google drive and it works: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx17tEcqrzavQUtzQzVqLTlkTVk/view

Comment: similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130823/google-map-iframe-kml-not-displaying-correctly?rq=1