# Google Map iframe KML not displaying correctly

Tags: google-maps, kml

Looking for help in why our embedded KML Google map stopped working today. This is the current code:

iframe width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=docs:%2F%2F0B0CyyOTyQR_7T0NfQmhVakFndG8&t=p&output=svembed">

Here is a link to the Google Map with the KML that the site is pulling from:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7SRdsTwGw_MTVJJMDVnZ3lhX2c/edit

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233983/how-to-embed-a-kml-file